# Nodejs mysql driver denying access with correct credentials

Tags: mysql, node.js, ubuntu

Im deploying adonis js to a digital oceon server and im confident my mysql credentials are correct in my .env. Yet adonis keeps rejecting the connection saying access denied for my user.
This is my .env

```
  PORT=3333
HOST=0.0.0.0
NODE_ENV=production
APP_KEY=2wEd7zY15oEDVu8uTz5VKagw3yn0RZkX
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
MYSQL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_USER=noble
MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
MYSQL_DB_NAME=adonisapp
```

My users are created using the mysql_native_password plugin which seems to be the problem since it connects without it but still rejects the connection afterward. How can i fix this

Comment: make sure you restart node js server after updating .env file

Comment: Actually i just found a fix that required me to manually insert the credentials in the database.js file. Works fine now